# Sending html content in mails using MailGun

Tags: mailgun

How can we set html tags inside the mail content while sending mail using mailgun api? When I send it, the tags are displaying as it is.

But in smtp, we can set it as , isBodyHtml=true

Answer (score 2):

Here is the quick code example that can help you to send email in HTML format.

```
        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "key-XXX");
        request.AddParameter("domain","yourdomain.com", ParameterType.UrlSegment);

        request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
        //request.AddParameter("from", "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandboxc.mailgun.org>");
        request.AddParameter("from", "from@mail.com");
        request.AddParameter("to", to);
        request.AddParameter("subject", subject);
        request.AddParameter("text", "Text view of this email is not supported. Please view this email in HTML format. Thank you.");

        //This will help you to send email in HTML format
        request.AddParameter("html", body);

        request.Method = Method.POST;

        RestResponse stat = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your html content (with the tags) in the 'html' parameter when calling the Mailgun API.
Taken from Mailgun homepage (the last line is what you are asking for):

```
POST /messages
  from = 'App <me@myapp.io>'
  to = 'bob@gmail.com'
  subject = 'Hello'
  text = 'Welcome to our amazing app!'
  html = '<p>Welcome to our amazing app!</p>'
```

Hope this helps